# Object Joined in Edit Mode Doesn't Look the Same In Object Mode

Tags: edit-mode, displacement, object-mode

I am having the problem where I snapped two meshes together in edit mode but it doesn't show up in object mode.  Anyone know why this is happening.  I thought it might be because I duplicated something that has a displace modifier on it and then tried to join those two together.  The draw type isn't set to bounds by the way.  Thanks!
[image]

[image]

Comment: could you share your file?

Comment: @moonboots I actually got it figured out.  It was the displacement modifier.  I just sub surfaced a rectangular prism and it worked.  Thanks though!